# Should garbage collection have run by now?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have had a C# application running for the past few weeks. When I first started it, it had ~10000K memory usage. Since then, I've checked and it's at a ~20000K memory footprint.

I don't know .Net garbage collection very well, but is this a sign that I definitely have a memory leak? Shouldn't the GC have run by now?

I've read into garbage collection here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

And they have the following conditions for when GC should run:

- The system has low physical memory. **(I have well over 70000K of memory left to use, so this shouldn't be triggered)**
- The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap
  surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously
  adjusted as the process runs. **(how do you define "acceptable" threshold?)**

Shouldn't I expect GC to have run in a few weeks timespan?

Comment: The most common reason people think .NET isn't collecting garbage is that they misunderstand what Task Manager is showing them and how .NET manages the heap. Just because _your_ program's direct memory consumption is reduced, that doesn't mean .NET has given the memory back to Windows. Or, maybe you do have a memory leak. Who knows? You didn't provide a good [mcve].

Comment: To verify whether there is a memory leak, do not use task manager. Instead use a proper memory profiler. There is one comes with Visual Stuidio.

Comment: Going from 10MB to 20MB without ever running the garbage collector is only possible on a server-class machine.  It is a very low amount of memory for a typical C# program, using the available RAM on the machine effectively is the best way to make code run fast and the CLR does it best to take advantage of it.  Looks like your program doesn't give it much of a chance.  You only have a leak when you can get it to climb constantly towards ~1.5 gigabytes.  You need to adjust the threshold between your ears :)

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't I expect GC to have run in a few weeks timespan?

Nope, you shouldn't expect GC.Collect to occur in timely manner.

> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is
>   true:
>
> - The system has low physical memory.
> - The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap    surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously
>     adjusted as the process runs.
> - The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have    to call this method, because the garbage collector runs
>     continuously.    This method is primarily used for unique situations
>     and testing.

Read this for more [fundamental](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx) details.